# How to take date frequent change (day by day)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to change date in every day in my result. How it is possible

like example:
WHERE 
`REPLY_dATE` BETWEEN '2017-03-17 12:00:00 AM' AND '2017-03-17 4:00:00 PM
I want to replace=====2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM====today_Date
                      2017-03-17 4:00:00 PM=======current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEAST()` for the first step:

```
LEAST(264, Round(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, REPLY_dATE))/480)) as WH
```

Use `CASE` for second step:

```
CASE WHEN ROUND((126720-sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, REPLY_dATE)))/480) < 0 THEN 0 
ELSE LEAST(264, Round(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, REPLY_dATE))/480))
END
```

If you need `WH` and `VH` as well, you can use a sub-query to avoid redundancy:

```
SELECT VH, WH,
CASE 
  WHEN (SELECT VH) < 0 THEN 0 
  ELSE (SELECT WH)
END AS MyComputedColumn
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  ROUND((126720-sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, REPLY_dATE)))/480) as VH,
  LEAST(264, Round(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, REPLY_dATE))/480)) as WH
  FROM bbt2.new_table
) AS X;
```

Comment: Second query isn't running

Comment: @Belbase1: I probably missed the ending `CASE` keyword. See if it is better now.

Comment: Still some problems sir didn't run

Comment: second query I give the name VH

Comment: Send me the `create` statement for your table.

Comment: `request_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,`reply_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL

Comment: I solved this problem:,ROUND(264-LEAST(264, Round(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Request_Date, REPLY_dATE))/480))) as VH

Comment: @Belbase1: Good to hear. This expression doesn't however produce what you described in the question.